# How did the twins get in 1940?

Tags: miss-peregrines-home, ransom-riggs

In *Hollow City*, Jacob and his friends go to London (while in the year 1940) and go under St. Paul's Cathedral looking for the peculiar pigeons. Before entering the loop that is under the coffin, they find two twins capable of echolocation. These twins have recently left their loop and somehow came into 1940 from it. We have learned previously that when peculiars exit a loop, they reenter their own time period; for example, Emma leaving a loop puts her in 1940 but Jacob leaving a loop would put him in the present. If the twins have just left their loop and ended up in the year 1940, they must have originally entered the loop at almost exactly the same time in that year as Jacob's team arrived, since people leave loops at the same time they entered. Loops can only be entered if they are from a previous time than the current one, and the twins appeared at just the right time in 1940, which would have to mean that the date of the twins' loop was just several days after the date of Mrs. Peregrine's loop, the one the children left. This is incredibly difficult to believe, so I'm suspecting that this is a plot hole.

Am I missing something? How is this possible? Is it just a plot hole?

EDIT: Actually, people don't come out of a loop at the same time that they entered. Actually, they come out *relative* to when the entered (as much time passes as time spent in the loop), so the twins must have entered years before at *just the right time.*